# Am getting error on installing Camera and react-native-qrcode-scanner (Build failed with an exception)

Tags: react-native, qr-code, react-native-camera

Please find the Error Image after installing below Libraries

```
1. npm add react-native-camera@git+https://git@github.com/react-native-community/react-native-camera.git
2. npm add react-native-qrcode-scanner
```

[image]

[image]

please help me on this,

thanks in advance

Comment: you are installing the app wrongly!

Comment: see the react-native camera installation here

https://react-native-community.github.io/react-native-camera/docs/installation.html

Comment: yes rizwan i followed the same steps in that link, it's working now. Thanks

Comment: Camera is working now, but am using Drawer navigation when i navigate to some other screens from Camera screen and when i return to Camera screen again it's showing black screen with some warning message like "PermissionDialogTitle and permissionDialogMessage are deprecated.Please use androidcameraPermissionOptions instead" what that means?

Comment: for camera you have to download permsission package to help you with!   try react-native-permissions